# I'm wondering why it takes two click of the button to complete this UIImageView Code?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

For REference:

```
@interface rjhccViewController : UIViewController{

int myInt;

IBOutlet UIImageView *testcontainer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *heightS;
    IBOutlet UILabel *widthS;
}

-(IBAction) img1;
-(IBAction) img2;

@end

-(IBAction)img1{

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.jpeg"];
[testcontainer setImage:img];
[testcontainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
int myInt = (int) img.size.height;
NSString *imgheight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:img.size.height] intValue]];
heightS.text = imgheight;
}
```

So I have this attached to a button. When I click the button the image shows up and the height gets reported but the container does not change size. When I click the button again it does go to the correct for the CGRectMake...no sure why?

Rob

Comment: Is testcontainer an `UIImageView`?

Comment: yes it is...I"ve been in Objective-C and Cocoa land for 2 days now. So fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the size of the UIImageView to be the same as the image after you've set the last one to the image property of the UIImageView try the following code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.jpeg"];
[testcontainer setImage:img];
[testcontainer sizeToFit];
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on this. What I'm trying to do is load the image into the UIImageView then resize that UIImageView and place it on the stage at a location with the button click. It loads theimage but it ignores the resizing of the UIImageView till the second button click.

Comment: Here is the weird thing too..if I leave `code`heightS.text = imgheight;`code` in the method it fails. If I remove it is works. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: How did you write the IBAction code with my method? show me the code.
If you want to print out the size of the image try the following code:
`heightS.text = NSStringFromCGSize(img.size);`

Comment: sorry for the late response...no dice...again when I write to the label and or text area it doesn't let the resize of the UIImageView to run.